# Backup Google Earth Engine Code to GitHub

Tags: google-earth-engine, github

I am really fresh to using GEE. I want to know if there was a way to backup any file to GitHub.

For example, I have a file called 'TestFile' and its contents are just:

```
print('Test')
```

Is there any way to export this to GitHub in GEE without having to save to my local drive?

Answer (score 0):

Your script files in the Earth Engine Code Editor are stored in Git repositories hosted at https://earthengine.googlesource.com/. I'm not aware of a way to copy those to GitHub without first `git clone`ing them to a machine of yours, but at least you can do that to back up all the scripts and history at once and repeatedly — you don't have to copy individual script texts.

Comment: What if I just wanted to download the scripts to my machine?

Comment: @BigDawg007 Then you can install git and use `git clone https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/<your user name>/default` to download a complete copy of your script repository.